# Missing Android components Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm developing an application  to Android on Visual Studio with Xamarin but I'm getting the following error when I open the project:

```
Error       An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project 'Sample'.
Project 'Sample' requires the following components installed on your machine: 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.4.0/appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.4.0/appcompat-v7-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/23.4.0/support-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/23.4.0/support-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0


Please double-click here to install it.

Intallation Errors: XA5209 Unzipping failed. Please download 'https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip:m2repository/com/android/support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0.aar' and extract it to the 'C:\Users\muril\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded' directory
XA5209 Reason: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\muril\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0\embedded\aapt\'.
XA5207 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\libs/internal_impl-23.4.0.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.
XA5207 Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\classes.jar' doesn't exist.           0
```

I'm tried some tutorials that I found on internet, but no success, I already tried to download manually the zip, but without success, if someone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: You should install those packages from Nuget.

Comment: @Tim Those packages already is installed from Nuget

Comment: Install a higher version of support libraries. You are installing v23 which is very old. Use something like v26 or v27

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks! Can you use the Answer field to I set the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support libraries is too old.

1- Go to **NuGet**

2- Click on "**Installed**"

3- Search for **Xamarin.Android.Support**

4- Update to version **25+**

- Xamarin.Android.Support.**Animated.Vector.Drawable**
- Xamarin.Android.Support.**v4**
- Xamarin.Android.Support.**v7.AppCompat**
- Xamarin.Android.Support.**Vector.Drawable**